# jQuery Mobile - when dialog is opened from Panel buttons do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and finding my dialog which is opened from a panel item is not enabling any button click or listview click and hover functionality.  The working panel html code which is opening my dialog is: -

```
<li data-icon="grid"><a href="#changeNameDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-theme="b">Change Name</a></li>
```

The dialog html which I've simplified as much as possible is: -

```
<div id="changeNameDialog" data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Change Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
            <ul id="nameList" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">j1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">j2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">j3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">j4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" onclick="putNameChange();">Change</button>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

If I change my panel list item data-rel attribute to be data-rel="page", the button and list click and hover functionality works fine i.e.

```
<li data-icon="grid"><a href="#changeNameDialog" data-rel="page" data-theme="b">Change Name</a></li>
```

The only thing that works on the Dialog is the dialogs (x) icon close button.  What is the Panel doing to the Dialog events?

Comment: Dialog should have `data-role=dialog`. Try opening it using programmatically like here http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/yAL5E/

Comment: Thanks for that Omar, I will do that.  I found the problem just now.  There is a canvas element on the page swallowing the Dialog events due a css setting on the canvas  i.e. z-index: 1;  JQM Popups have a large z-index (1100) whereas a JQM Dialog doesn't.

Comment: @abdu lol, I didn't solve this ;)